# saving picture in media library with the same size as phone's screen size in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In my windows phone application I want to save picture in media library to the same size as phone's screen size.
I am doing this

```
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(480, 800);
        wb.Render(myitem, null);  // myItem is a UI Element
        wb.Invalidate(); 

        // create temporary image from it
        Image tmpImg = new Image();
        tmpImg.Source = wb;

        // this is required by WriteableBitmap 
        tmpImg.Measure(new Size(480, 800));
        tmpImg.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100));

        WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(480, 800);
        writeableBitmap.Render(tmpImg, null);
        writeableBitmap.Invalidate(); 

        using (var mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary())
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            { 
                writeableBitmap .SaveJpeg(stream, writeableBitmap .PixelWidth, writeableBitmap   
                                          .PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var picture = mediaLibrary.SavePicture("chk.jpg", stream); 
            }
        }
```

I get this
[image]

I want this
 [image]

Comment: Phone's screen size isn't necessarily 480x800, it can go up to 1080x1920.

Comment: yes..what approach should i use to get the desired result ?

Comment: You realize you'll have to crop that image before you get even near the last step.  And a contextual crop, as well.

Comment: You should set the `Width` and `Height` properties of the `Image` control and decide the stretching method because devices have different aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about how to get the physical pixel size of the phone, then try this:

```
var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
var width = frame.ActualWidth;
var height = frame.ActualHeight;

double resolutionscale;
#if WINDOWS_APP
    resolutionscale = ((int)Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().ResolutionScale / 100d);
#elif WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
    resolutionscale = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel;
    resolutionscale = Math.Pow(resolutionscale, 2d);
#elif WINDOWS_PHONE
    resolutionscale = ((int)Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayProperties.ResolutionScale / 100d);
#endif    

var physicalSize = new Size(width * resolutionscale, height * resolutionscale);
```

Comment: i will try this...is my approach correct .? i mean is there any other actual method or something that do the saving process with correct image size ?

Comment: Well, if it compiles and if you get ANY result, then you're on a very good way. But honestly I don't know what I'm seeing on the screenshots...